# Code and Data Security considerations during website deployment?

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, web-hosting

I will soon be hosting my MVC site to an external provider (I am yet to finalize the hosting services company).
My website is developed using ASP.NET MVC 4 and it is using SQL Server 2008 as its database.
I will publish 3 applications under single domain:

- MVC 4 external site - Public access
- WCF service - Consumed by external site
- MVC 4 internal site - Restricted access (admin and configuration
  purpose)

There are few questions striking me at the moment -

1. How can I make my code secure so that it can't be refactored from
   its DLLs?
2. How to make CSHTML (razor) views secure so that noone from the
   hosting company can see its internals?
3. Finally, how to make SQL Server database secure so that no one in
   hosting company can open it through SSMS?

These all questions are interrelated and so I have posted in a single question.
I am not sure, if anyone in hosting company can really bother about the code or database of their customers, but its just a security consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: You cannot. You need to have a minimum amount of trust toward your hoster. If you don't, find someone else.

The only way to have the kind of security you want would be to host the website yourself, on a machine where you yourself control physical access (i.e. on site). Next best solution would be to rent a root server, but even then you cannot lock out the hosting company reliably.

You can obfuscate the DLLs to make decompiling harder (but not impossible), but there is no way (that I know of) to do that with Razor views. I would not recommend doing that for a website either way. The database cannot be obfuscated like that by design, especially if it is on a shared server.

Long story short: If you run code or store data on a machine you do not own, you can no longer completely control access to it.